# Python - O que é enum?

Tags: python, funções, enums

Eu usei a função type em um objeto e o retornado foi: `<enum 'Button'>`.

O que isso significa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enum é basicamente uma lista de valores constantes. O uso de enums torna mais fácil para o programador acessar uma informação. O Enum associa, de forma automática ou manual, um valor numérico à uma string. [Veja aqui.](https://cadernodelaboratorio.com.br/2017/04/27/o-tipo-enum-em-python/)